# Regular Expression of {w : w contains an even number of 0s and exactly two 1s}

Tags: automata, regular-expressions, discrete-mathematics

I know the answer if it was OR would be `(1*01*01*)* U 0*10*10*`, but with the AND I have no clue how this can be achieved. There are lot's concatenations that I can't cover by getting the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

There are a limited number of cases.  For instance, one case has an odd number of 0's followed by consecutive 1's, followed by an odd number of 0's.  Another case is that there is an initial 1, followed by an even number of 0's, followed by a terminating 1.  List all the cases and make up an OR-type expression to cover them all.

Comment: Got it, I will.